# Book series of warriors who channel magic through singing

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m trying to locate the name of a series of books I read about 20 years ago. I think they were older but not certain.

I think there were 5-8 books in the series.

The main character in the first few books is a warrior who learns that despite being an accomplished fighter he actually has a stronger ability with magic through song. He learns to sing and channels his magic needed to defeat some major evil darkness coming to the land. Eventually he does, marries an equally talented magical singing woman, have kids and go on to rule the kingdom.

By the end of the 2nd or 3rd book, they learn to transcend life and become gods, so their kids end up inheriting the kingdom and the challenge of defeating the major evil entity that has returned years later. The son is smart but has no magic and ends up betraying everyone to the evil side and gets imprisoned? By the last book though, he sees the error of his ways and teams up with his sister to save everyone from the major evil entity. Or something like that.

Comment: Could they be the [Shannara Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannara). The singing sounds a lot like [Wishsong of Shannara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wishsong_of_Shannara).

Comment: No, I actually started reading those last year and unfortunately, they aren't related.

Comment: [The Spellsong Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellsong_Cycle) is another singing is magic series, but that looks like the only overlap with the series in the question. Still it's here as a wild guess.

Comment: Yeah, it's not that one either, though it sounds interesting. That link also led me to the SpellSinger series, and although that one also has 8 books in the series, it's totally different as well. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the series by Sara Douglass: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayfarer_Redemption

This series is two trilogies, beginning with the novel The Wayfarer Redemption. It takes places on a world that has different races of humans. One race, the Icarii, can fly and do magic through song. The male protagonist, Axis, is of this race. However, through some plot contrivance I can't fully remember he's not able to do it or perhaps unable to do it well until he meets and falls in love with a wingless woman from another of the races, Azhure. Even though Azhure is not Icarii, she either can do magic like they can or can do Icarii magic with Axis only. There is another woman, Faraday, who drives a lot of the early plot (the first 2 novels I believe). She is in an abusive relationship with the leader of the Achar people who hate all magic and have tried to exterminate the Icarii. She is the female protagonist in the first novel and a lot of the book is about her, she is a surprisingly well developed character for a book of this type that also has a male protagonist. The first trilogy of the series (Wayfarer, Enchanter, and StarMan) works out how Axis and Azhure get to be together permanently, overcome evil leaders of the human races, some kind of world destroying demon, and start a family. They end up ruling the Icarii people as the SunSoar family.

The second trilogy jumps forward a bit to the next generation. The eldest of the SunSoar children is grown and an outcast from his people for being evil. There is a younger son, Caelum, who is grown or nearly so, who must take over the Icarii leadership after his parents ascend to the astral plane to live in love and peace forever feeling that they have done enough for the world. This trilogy is really twisty and it's difficult to explain. The main thing is that the older brother was under mind control by a demon from when he was still in the womb. He is not really responsible for the evil things he did. He is able to communicate telepathically with the younger brother and they end up working together, against the laws of their people and the commands of their parents, to avert an apocalypse that would have destroyed all life on the planet. The enemy they fight was the true Big Bad behind the enemy their parents fought in the first trilogy. This enemy is the demon who controlled the older brother until he was able to secretly escape some of the mind control and begin making some of his own small decisions. Faraday makes a comeback in this trilogy as well and has more power. She also gets treated a lot better.

Comment: Wow. Funny how many of the details you forget over the years but after confirming with the posted link, that's definitely it! I spent years wondering & thanks to you, the mystery is finally solved! Thank you!

Comment: @Vegeta: You're welcome. I have the same issue with books I've read. People have helped me, glad I can help you.